# Backend creation of 3D tours from 2D images

Tags: image, image-manipulation

I am looking for a tool to create 3D tours from 2D images. I am very flexible when it comes to the front-end, I am just looking for a tool that upon receiving some 2D pictures and some data on where they were taken / where they have to be placed, it is able to re-create the 3D environment. I only found solutions that involve manual intervention (3D tour builders basically - I am not going to link them because they are commercial and I don't want to advertise any). I am looking to the closest automatised solution.

One close solution I found is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@egjs/view360 which is a viewing solution rather than a solution to solve my problem.

Thanks!

EDIT: I know this is asking for a tool rather than a proper question like SO is expecting but... I really don't know how to look for this and have no prior experience in doing it.

Comment: Hmm, so you basically want an open source version of google street view -like technology - is that right?

Comment: Well, that would be an overkill. I'm trying to automatically create a virtual 3D tour of an indoors environment!

Comment: I have got the ball rolling with an answer!  Happy hunting !

Answer (score 1):

I googled the phrase "open source version of google street view" and immediately found:

https://searchengineland.com/openstreetmap-debuts-google-street-view-alternative-openstreetview-257189

"OpenStreetMap debuts Google Street View alternative: OpenStreetView"

This question on another site:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80553/is-there-an-opensource-way-of-making-streetview-panoramas

Seems to be asking exactly the same thing:

> "I'm interested in making streetview[-like] panoramas and am curious if there are any opensource approaches that I should consider for both making and publishing these panoramas.

Could this be the answer ?

http://hugin.sourceforge.net

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugin_(software)

and wow:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_stitching_software

Comment: Part of my problem is indeed to stitch pictures to create a panorama, the issue I see with what I hunted down in your resources are the following:
- There seems to be no way to automatically do that given my premises
- They only offer stitching pics rather than 3D tours (of an indoors environment)
I'll keep looking through them to see if I missed something just in case! Thanks!

Comment: ah a **3D TOUR** !!  I fear, you may be asking a lot!   :O  that would be an interesting project.   Good luck!  Maybe someone here will have an answer!

Comment: @Masiar , for the sake of keeping the site tidy, can you tick any answer - cheers !!   hope your project went well

Comment: Not really the answer to my question though?